# Why does CMake generator for Unix Makefiles delete files?

Tags: linux, cmake, generator

I have a rather complex CMake configuration, which contains several `execute_process` commands which create files during the configuration stage. Sometimes after some changes in the CMake configuration the generation stage deletes these files. I can reproduce that.

I've checked that the files exist after the configuration stage but are gone after the Makefile generation and before actually calling `make`.

The files are created in some cases simply by `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy` and in other cases by calling a script with `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P` which contains a `configure_file` call to replace some placeholders in a template.

The files are created in the source tree. Their purpose is to provide the developer with some initial code. When the developer has edited the files, they should be committed to version control and not be re-created again unless they are missing. I have `add_custom_command`s to recreate the files if they're missing, but those are not the culprit.

I know, you'd prefer a simple test example, but unfortunately this is not so easy to create, so my question is:

**What might be the cause and how can I debug that?**

Unfortunately, the `--trace` options of `cmake` do not give any log data about the generation stage.

### Versions

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- CMake 3.5.1 (belonging to Ubuntu 16.04)

## Update

I've compiled CMake itself with the current master commit (696b2d4) and the behavior is still the same.

By running CMake under a debugger I've discovered that the line

```
cmSystemTools::RemoveFile(fname);
```

in function `cmGlobalGenerator::CheckRuleHashes(std::string const& pfile, std::string const& home)` actually deletes the files. It is called from `cmGlobalGenerator::Generate()`.

Comment: Does `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` == `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` in your case? If yes, maybe it's what causing the problem?

Comment: @arrowd: No, I have the standard setup with a ``build`` directory below the ``CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`` as ``CMAKE_BINARY_DIR``.

Comment: "after some changes in the CMake configuration the generation stage deletes these files." As far as I know, on configuration state CMake can only remove `CMakeCache.txt` when compiler's settings has been changed and the files in `CMakeFiles/` directory. All other files could be removed either with `execute_process` or `file(REMOVE)`.

Answer (score 0):

With further debugging (see update in the question) I've found the cause of my problem.

### CMake's behavior

CMake's global generator creates the file `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/CMakeRuleHashes.txt`. It contains a line for every custom command with outputs. Each line contains a hash and the path to the first output of the custom command.

The hash is made over the current binary dir of the custom command and the entire content of the `COMMAND` arguments of `add_custom_command`.

On generation CMake executes `cmGlobalGenerator::CheckRuleHashes` to check if the hashes are still up to date. If a hash is not up to date the corresponding output file will be removed, obviously to trigger re-execution of the custom command in the build stage.

### Cause of my problem

As mentioned in the question I execute the file creation command with `execute_process` during configuration and call `add_custom_command` with the same file creation command to trigger re-creation of the file in case it was missing.

So, CMake creates a hash line in its `CMakeRuleHashes.txt` for the file to be created.

Some of my `add_custom_command` calls are contained in a CMake file included from different `CMakeLists.txt` belonging to different sub-directories of the source. Depending on my actual configuration only specific sub-directories are added with `add_subdirectory`.

Thus, because the sub-directory is part of the hash of the custom command, the hash changes depending on the sub-directory added which includes the custom command. The changed hash then causes the deletion of the output file.

### Conclusion

I have to redesign my CMake configuration to resolve the dependency of the custom command on the CMake binary directory.

### Debugging generation stage

This could be done by compiling CMake itself as `Debug` build type and run it under a debugger.